# ImportXML Xpath Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

I wish you a good evening. I am currently trying to create an automated google table for certain PC parts in order to have an exact overview. The problem is that too much text is imported and then incorrectly inserted in the table. I would like to have these sorted more precisely. See image. I only started to deal with the ImportXML xpath today. Since I don't want to sit on it for the rest of the evening after work, I ask for help here. I hope it's clear what it's about. I get my information from the websites Alternate and Mindfactory (Germany)
i would like to apologize if my english is not perfect. This is not my native language
[sheet picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3JgE.png)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is only a single row. `OFFSET` ([reference](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en)) can be used to achieve it:

```
=OFFSET(TRANSPOSE(...), 0, 0, 1)
```

Comment: i did that, but now matter what i do, i am getting error.
error
Error parsing the formula.

=OFFSET(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(A2;B2)), 0, 0, 1)

Comment: I can't seem to be able import the `A2` URL; a simple `IMPORTXML` of that page gives me a could not fetch error. What error does it give, to you?

Comment: https://imgur.com/KDLjbiw

its just an error. the grey part on the left is the original, right side is the one with offset. ignore the second "=" its the same error with only one "="

Comment: It seems to work for me. This could be caused by your locale. Try changing the commas (`,`) with a semicolons (`;`).